# Check Axios request url before sending

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, axios

API requests are failing because the URL generated by Axios is incorrect due to my config. I know what the request url is suppose to look like, so I want to see the request url Axios generates.

I can point Axios to my local server and see the requests there, but I want to debug this on the client. I want to play with the config, and see how the requests change. Is there a way to output the request url from Axios before or after sending?

```
// param format
{ address: 'Vancouver', key: GOOGLE_API_KEY }

// Geocode sample
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

_request = async (...args) => {
  const { outputFormat, params } = args
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com`,
  })

  const response = await instance.get('/maps/api/geocode/${outputFormat}?', {
    params,
  })

  // I want to see the url generated by Axios so I can debug the issue

  console.log(response) 
}
```

I am within the `Expo`, `React Native` environment.

Working example using fetch:

```
const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=vancouver&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

**Solution used:**

```
_request = async (obj) => {
  const { outputFormat, params } = obj

  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com`,
  })

  instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    console.log(config)
    return config
  }, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })

  const response = await instance.get(`/maps/api/geocode/${outputFormat}`, {
    params,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can turn on debug mode and look at the network tab as mentioned in the other answer, or you can intercept `axios` and console.log or do whatever you want with the request before it's sent:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log(config)
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Comment: I am getting a request fail with status code 400. I tried using the interceptor, but I am not getting anything from it.

Comment: The interceptor is working. Issue was that trying to do `(...args)` results in getting an array, which results in an undefined params, which errors out.

Answer (score 15):

You can just use [`axios#getUri([config])`](https://github.com/axios/axios#user-content-axiosgeturiconfig) ([source](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4f98acc57860721c639f94f5772138b2af273301/lib/core/Axios.js#L59)) to perform the same logic as the request. It merges the configurations (e.g. the given `config` and the instance configuration), merges the `url` with the `baseURL`, and appends any `params` using the `paramSerializer`.

Comment: It does not actually use the `baseURL`, which is a shame.

Comment: There's an [pull request](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/2555) opened for months to fix this issue, hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Comment: Untill then: `config.baseURL.replace(/\/+$/, '') + $axios.getUri(config)` // absolute URL

Comment: The `baseURL` issue was fixed as of 0.26.1: https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3737